# Javascript intellisense with Dojo/Dijit is Visual Studio 2008

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, intellisense, dojo

I know that Visual Studio 2008 support JavaScript intellisense as I am using it with Jquery.  I am wondering if anyone has ever explored how to get other libraries like Dojo and Dijit to work with it as well.  I would assume you would have to provide the ///reference tag to your custom code but would still need a vsdoc for visual studio to look in.

Just curious if anyone has tried this or has any suggestions.  I might have to hand roll the vsdoc, which might not be too hard based on the api.xml documentation.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official Intellisense file for Dojo unfortunately. We could look up the spec and formulate something specific (like we do with Komodo .cix), it is just a matter of using the existing doc parser to scan over the code and generate whatever needs generated.

If you do hand-roll a vsdoc completion file, we'd love to have it. Or if you need any assistance using the doc parser to generate it feel free to contact me offlist (I'm 'dante' @ the toolkit domain) and we can see about getting something out there.

Answer (score 1):

We use Visual Assist plugin, and it does pretty well, only thing it lacks is list methods function because of the way you declare objects in Dojo with functions as property values, VA has trouble parsing these. Its OK with old school prototypes though.

Answer (score 0):

They are not officially supported for VS2008, but you may be able to get them to work. Of course, they don't have any of the meta comments in them. If you get any errors, you can create a -vsdoc version of the library and try to edit it to get past the error messages.

JavaScript IntelliSense in VS2010 will be much more robust and you will be able to get good IntelliSense (again without the meta-data) on a much wider range of 3rd party libraries.